# How to Handle Two Overlapping Twitter Bootstrap Modals

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a standard Twitter Bootstrap modal on my page:

```
<div class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3>Comments</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Please provide a comment:</p>
    <textarea id="comment"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save comment</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, I am saving the comment via AJAX and close the modal when a successful save happens.  However, I have a global AJAX error handler, which itself opens a modal when any AJAX calls encounter an error (not just for the comments AJAX call):

```
<div id="error-modal" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3>Error</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    </div>
</div>
```

The modal-body is filled in by the error handler and, by default, the new modal is placed on top of the existing modal. However, the modal backdrop for the new modal is behind the original modal, which still allows for interaction with it.

Is there a way to give the error modal backdrop a different z-index? Right now, the modal backdrop is modal agnostic and doesn't have a modal specific id/class.

Or are there any good plugins that deal with multiple Twitter Bootstrap modals?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It might be worth checking out this [Bootstrap Modal](https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal) plugin.

In the demo here...
http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/

...one of the examples has "Stackable" modals, and as far as I can tell, you are not able to interact with the old modal behind the new modal; i.e., you first have to click the background of the new modal to make the new modal go away and gain access to the old modal. (Note the example does give different `id`s to each modal.)

As an aside, I considered using this plugin at one point, but I think in part this article provided an argument for not using modals for *inline editing*: [http://www.keepitslickstupid.com/ (from web.archive.org)](https://web.archive.org/web/20141221125725/http://www.keepitslickstupid.com/)  (see section 3, "Modal dialogs are so 2002")

Comment: Hi, I also want to open modal box with overlap other. i can do this but able to click on lower modal box. i am using bootstrap 2.3.1

Comment: second link no longer available

Comment: @beauXjames - re: "3-essential-ux-ideas" link... archived version here: https://web.archive.org/web/20141221125725/http://www.keepitslickstupid.com/

Comment: thx, but I was just pointing it out...the archived version is incomplete (often images don't get the same treatment as text content)...I recommend just noting or deleting the link above...I'm sure there's plenty of other articles demoting the use of modals

Answer (score 4):

This is how I tackled it. I was showing error messages from an AJAX call started within the modal in a bootbox. It caused a mess. So here's what I did to the z-indexes:

```
.bootbox.modal {
    z-index: 1070;
}

.bootbox.modal + .modal-backdrop {
    z-index: 1060;
}
```

What happens here is that the initial z-index for the backdrop is 1040 and the modal is 1050. As bootbox adds a modal and backdrop at the end of the page, I gave the bootbox a z-index of 1070, so it stays on the absolute top, and used the "+" selector in CSS to only select the modal-backdrop that comes directly after the bootbox, and changed its z-index to 1060. This now overlaps the previous modal, allowing the focus to remain on the bootbox.

If you're not using bootbox, I think you can assign a custom class to the secondary modal and work your way from there. I haven't seen how the modal backdrops stack up if you have predefined modals, but just inspect the elements and choose your CSS selector accordingly.

Cheers

Comment: Nice solution! It solves my problem using bootbox.alert while a bootstrap modal dialog is open.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a non-answer depending on your perspective, but I'll give it a go:

I faced the very same problem a while ago. Instead of opening another modal, I decided to have the ajax error handler simply prepend the error message to the already opened modal (if there is none, an empty modal is first opened).

This is simpler in terms of programming (no other hack or plugin required) and *IMHO* also from user's perspective. Sometimes less is more.

I leave the decision as to which approach to pick to whoever might come across this in the furure...